# Mystery display -- Missing portions of server feedback in Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell, meteor

What's up with this?  I'm trying to use Windows10 PowerShell to interact with a Meteor application.  I'm having a heck of a time displaying feedback from the server thru the PowerShell.  Here's a typical screen shot:

[image: PowerShell Screen Shot]

At first glance it looks okay... but... what's up with that big blank zone to the left of the warning about bcrypt?  Here's a simple text copy paste from that same screen.

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
W20160829-11:13:55.719(-7)? (STDERR) Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
W20160829-11:13:55.780(-7)? (STDERR) While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
W20160829-11:13:55.782(-7)? (STDERR) approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
W20160829-11:13:55.785(-7)? (STDERR) In order to use the native implementation instead, run
W20160829-11:13:55.787(-7)? (STDERR)
W20160829-11:13:55.789(-7)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save bcrypt
W20160829-11:13:55.791(-7)? (STDERR)
W20160829-11:13:55.794(-7)? (STDERR) in the root directory of your application.
I20160829-11:13:55.805(-7)? Execution from imports/startup/server/emailServer.js smtp://postmaster%40sandbox57668b25b40b496
I20160829-11:13:55.808(-7)? Executing /imports/startup/server/index.js
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
   Type Control-C twice to stop.
```

I'm thinking its a Polar Bear in a Snow Storm issue. The raw server feedback data is there, you just can't see it. The copy of the server log errors and time are written in exactly the same color as the background.  I've made changes to background color, but none of them seem to work very well.  It's not clear to me on where those settings for that class of message exist.  Here's my properties pull down box:

[image: PowerShell Properties Box]

As you can see I only have options for Screen Background/Text colors and Popups background / Text colors. It's like those server warnings are a different classification of output. One that I am unable to even identify or modify. Anybody know what is going on here? Is there a way to fix this so I can easily see ALL the feedback from the server?

And yes, I'm doing development, so I'm running this localhost, Windows 10.

Comment: @Mer Clearly not. Perhaps you didn't read my entire posting.  Read it again, twice. Check out the quote: `I've made changes to background color, but none of them seem to work very well.` Look at the TWO photos.  There is no place to change the font color / background of the error message. You can only change "Screen" and "Popup".  There is no place to change the background and font colors for a "mystery error" type.

Comment: Reset colors to default and run it again.  If that's the problem, then there you go.  Also, try it in ISE, without touching the colors.  Then try it with different of the preloaded themes.  `Tools, Options, Colors and Fonts` shows much more than your dialog box in the way of output streams.

Comment: @Xalorous, I must be totally doing this wrong.  There is no way to 'reset' the color back to a factory default. Just not possible. You get a choice for `Defaults` and one for `Properties`.  Defaults doesn't seem to do anything.      When you set the background in black you the mystery text goes to black on black.  I'd be happy to review the screen prints in your answer on how to do this, but I can't figure it out.  I've tried to use the Windows Powershell ISE, but it's way slow, and I can't figure out how to break out of Meteor (Control-C just doesn't work..)

Comment: Perhaps meteor is the source of the issue here.  I'm not familiar with it.  Also, I do not know how to reset the shell colors.

Comment: Hang on a sec.  You're using a powershell shell to launch meteor javascript apps?  Is it permitted to use the command shell instead?  Try start, run, cmd.exe, then executing your meteor app.